# Incorrect application name in Spring Cloud Sleuth logs

Tags: spring-boot, logback, tomcat8, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have two Spring boot applications - Application1 and Application2. Both applications are using Spring Cloud Sleuth. Both applications are deployed on same external tomcat. Below are the details of configurations -
 - To provide application name I have added separate bootstrap.yml file for each application in resources folder. 
 - I have also provided active profile in bootstrap.yml file. 
 - Application name is also added in application-${profile}.properties file as well. 
 - After doing that I have added logback-spring.xml in classpath. 
Now when I start tomcat server with both applications I am getting first application name in Spring Cloud Sleuth logs for both applications.

I am using Spring boot 1.4.1 and Spring cloud sleuth 1.0.10

EDIT:
I have added application name in bootstrap.yml but still I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

As we write in the docs (I think we do write about it) you have to provide the name in bootstrap yaml when providing your custom logback. Please check the docs where we describe how to work with custom logback.  http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in my question, I have added application name in bootstrap.yml file but still I am facing same issue

Comment: Loggers are designed to be global per JVM. I'm not even sure it is possible to have 2 different output formats in the same process. It might be, but I never tried.

Comment: If I use default Spring boot logging it works as expected. Only with custom logback-spring.xml I am facing this issue. Is it possible to add appender in default spring boot logger?

Comment: Don't know. You could raise an issue in Spring Boot if you think that multiple `logback-spring.xml` in the same JVM should work and it isn't.

Comment: Have you checked out the docs how we fix it in the custom logback?

Comment: Yes I tried that and in that case I am getting logs as below -

Comment: 2016-10-24 16:40:14.351  INFO [Application1,,,] [Application1,,,] 12408 --- [ost-startStop-1]

Comment: For application 2 this is the log - 2016-10-24 11:11:15.014  INFO [Application1,,,] [Application2,,,] 12408 --- [ost-startStop-1]

Comment: I think you need to upload your sample somewhere. Without this were just guessing

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak, we are still facing this issue with version Hoxton.SR7, when two spring boot apps are deployed on an external tomcat, that the spring.application.name is taken from the one which was deployed first. Is this solvable or is sleuth not working for multiple apps in a single webcontainer?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in our project where we deployed two spring boot wars in one ibm liberty web container. We fixed it by providing a custom logback-spring.xml. Following are the configurations that fixed it:
**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
<property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" value="%clr(%5p) %clr([${springAppName},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]){yellow}" />
<!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
          value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
<appender name="FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <file>${server.output.dir}logs/myapplication1.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${server.output.dir}logs/myapplication1%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!--<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">-->
            <!--<maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>-->
        <!--</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>-->
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="com.sample.controllers.MyController" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

**Make sure it is included in classpath by maven**

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
              <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/application.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.yml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

**And add the following entry in your src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml**

spring:
   application:
     name: myapplication1
   jmx:
     default-domain: myapplication1

Have this configuration in each of the two spring boot applications with different application names